# javascript rickshaw graph auto scale

Tags: scale, rickshaw

I am plotting with rickshaw graph,  in the y-axis, I need to scale it properly.

I could do something like this:

```
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
  element: document.getElementById("chart"),
  renderer: 'multi',
  min:165000000,
  max:176000000,
  width: 1000,
  height: 500,
  ....
```

but I hope it can automatically scale in the y-axis,  instead of hard code "min" and "max" here.  anyone has a simple example for this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to go through all the data in your series, and detect the min and max.

There is an example on the Rickshaw website for scaled series: http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/scaled.html

If you look at the source code, you will see that they're manually going through the series data and finding the data extremums.

Answer (score 0):

As ArtBIT suggested you have to go through your array and parse each element in order to find the min and max value.

Let's say that you have an array of *prices* that are going to be on the graph.

For example:

```
var y_ticks = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y( {
  graph: graph,
  orientation: 'left',
  tickFormat: function(y) {return parseInt(y);},
  tickValues: [minArray(prices), maxArray(prices)],
  element: document.getElementById('y_axis')
});

function minArray(a) {
  var min=a[0]; for(var i=0,j=a.length;i<j;i++){min=a[i]<min?a[i]:min;}
  return min;
}

function maxArray(a) {
  var max=a[0]; for(var i=0,j=a.length;i<j;i++){max=a[i]>max?a[i]:max;}
  return max;
}
```

minArray(a) and maxArray(a) finds the min and max of the input array a.